# Temporal Table result to variable doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, transactions, temporal-tables

Im traying to set the result of a temporal table to a variable doing this im i doing somthig wrong??

```
WITH Consolidado_B (CANTIDAD,CALIDAD) AS(
    select 
        SUM(cbs) [Cantidad],
        'BLANCOS' CALIDAD
    from CBases c
    inner join v_Bases v on v.CODIGO=c.basecodi
    where v.[NOMBRE COMPLETO] like '%blanco%' and
    c.colorcodi=@COLORCODI
    union
    select
        SUM(cbs),
        'ACCENT'
    from CBases c
    inner join v_Bases v on v.CODIGO=c.basecodi
    where v.[NOMBRE COMPLETO] like '%Acce%' 
    and c.colorcodi=@COLORCODI
)
SET @TOTALBASES=
(
SELECT sum(CANTIDAD) TOTAL 
FROM Consolidado_B
)
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? (Also, there is no need to SHOUT in your title, we can read your "inside voice" fine.) Is it simply due to you using `SET` instead of `SELECT`? If so, this is just a typographical error.

Comment: Sorry for the shouts, it just says that thers a syntax error close to the `SET` so i try instead of using the `SET` try with `SELECT COLUMN INTO @VARIABLE FROM TABLE` but it didnt work anyway the syntax error persist

Comment: And yet you still don't tell us what that error is. :/

Comment: Surely you want to use `UNION ALL` even though it is unlikely that the two summed amounts generated in your CTE will be exactly the same. But I now see you include a literal in the resultset so you narrowly avoid this logic error - at the expense of more complexity and less efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can just use a `SELECT`.  But this would be simpler as:

```
select @TOTALBASES = SUM(cbs) 
from CBases c join
     v_Bases v
     on v.CODIGO=c.basecodi
where c.colorcodi = @COLORCODI or
      (v.[NOMBRE COMPLETO] like '%blanco%'  or v.[NOMBRE COMPLETO] like '%Acce%') ;
```

This is not 100% equivalent if `[NOMBRE COMPLETO]` can match both conditions -- and you actually want those counted twice.  But, it is much, much more efficient.  If that is the case, the query can be tweaked to handle this -- without all the complication of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention it, i'll guess the error message is : Subquery returned more than 1 value.  or Consolidado_B isn't defined.

The CTE need to be with the select statement, not separate with the SET statement.

Try this :

```
WITH Consolidado_B (CANTIDAD,CALIDAD) AS(
    select 
        SUM(cbs) [Cantidad],
        'BLANCOS' CALIDAD
    from CBases c
    inner join v_Bases v on v.CODIGO=c.basecodi
    where v.[NOMBRE COMPLETO] like '%blanco%' and
    c.colorcodi=@COLORCODI
    union
    select
        SUM(cbs),
        'ACCENT'
    from CBases c
    inner join v_Bases v on v.CODIGO=c.basecodi
    where v.[NOMBRE COMPLETO] like '%Acce%' 
    and c.colorcodi=@COLORCODI
)
SELECT @TOTALBASES= sum(CANTIDAD) 
FROM Consolidado_B
```

Comment: Ohh i got it now ty @MLeblanc

Comment: The subquery *couldn't* return more than one value.That would be impossible with a query like `SELECT SUM(Column) FROM Object;`.